# CMake "Could not read from count file."

Tags: cmake

In my main CMakeLists file I include() another cmake file which has these two lines:

```
add_custom_target(myTarget)
add_custom_command(TARGET myTarget COMMAND echo ARGS "Here is an echo" WORKING_DIRECTORY ${PARENT_DIR})
```

Here is the output after I build and run 'make myTarget':

```
Could not read from count file.
Here is an echo
Built target myTarget
Could not read from count file.
```

I have no idea what this 'count file' is that it tells me about twice. Can anyone tell me what this means?

Cmake version 3.6.2

Comment: You're right, it was actually happening for all targets. You we're also correct about the reason, bad write permissions on the binary directory.
Thanks for the help. Can you make the comment an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "count file" is where CMake logs the build progress, so that it can give its "% complete" output.

I seriously doubt the "could not read from count file" is related to your two lines. Insufficient write permissions to the binary directory, perhaps, or some path mismatch?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem (in a build directory where I had accidentally called cmake from a sub directory). Removing all contents of the build directory and running cmake again fixed the issue.

Comment: +1 This is the simplest fix for the OP problem - just rm the build directory, re-create it,  and run cmake again. The problem sometimes happens after a git merge, but don't bother trying to figure out what exactly caused it.